# Use bash sed command for double backslash replacement

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

The previous pipeline artifact is loaded for checking (file name is cache_deploy_.properties).
The file contains every module and the last changed timestamp.
A file is updated with timestamps (hashcode) if the module has changed from the previous run (yes similar to a Git commit).
After this file has been updated, it is published as a pipeline artifact for the next run.

File contents example

```
#Tue Aug 01 11:09:53 AEST 2023
D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\PRIE\\Programs\\IEW340P3.NSP=ec656d00d2e5e12ae1eb3aa9771af464\!\:\!null
D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\PRMR\\Maps\\MRJ400M1.NSM=c4b10568d2dd5f88f255cf0192b0945d\!\:\!null
```

What is happening is, next time a pipleline runs, the azure "user agent" is different,
So the modules being checked in the file are a thought to be a different location

```
echo $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
D\:\\agent_work\\agent-1\\217\\s\\    ----> (compared to previous run as above D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\)
```

So when it goes to check this file, the recorded information will no longer match (as different "user agent" in the file).
And the pipeline will try to create new entries for EVERY module.
I cannot control the output to the file... otherwise I would remove the user agent (propriatry JAR from a vendor and Ant Script).
It uses the complete file location in it's analysis to determine what to do with the changed modules.

What this is trying to achieve... need to rename ALL the lines in the file with the previous "user agent" to match the current "user agent"
Use a bash script in a pipeline build to change the user agent in the artifact loaded file.
I am trying the following, but might need some help please.

Script example

```
echo '#Tue Aug 01 14:16:13 AEST 2023
D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\PRIE\\Programs\\IEW340P3.NSP=ec656d00d2e5e12ae1eb3aa9771af464\!\:\!null
D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\PRUT\\Maps\\UTRESM06.NSM=eb0e29846516c74be5763a8cd9ab22d8\!\:\!null
D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\PRMR\\Maps\\MRJ400M1.NSM=c4b10568d2dd5f88f255cf0192b0945d\!\:\!null' > myconfig.txt
file="myconfig.txt"

# userAgent='D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\' #This is user agent is in the file no need for fixing!
userAgent='D\:\\agent_work\\agent-1\\170\\s\\'
echo "Current User agent:" $userAgent

if grep -F $userAgent $file; then
    echo "Found user agent, no need to replace"
else
    echo "User Agent not found in file, need to replace with current"
    var=$(sed '2q;d' $file) # just need to check for prev agent on 2nd line
    substr="s" # this 's' is the end position of the agent 
    prefix=#${var%%$substr*} #gives us the index nuumber of 's'
    index=$((${#prefix}+2)) # add 2 to cater for the // after s
    replaceUser=${var:0:index} #finally have the string to search the file for to replace
    echo "Previous user agent:" $replaceUser

    sed -i --debug "s/'$replaceUser'/$userAgent/g" $file # <-- This is not working
fi
```

```
Output:
Current User agent: D\:\\agent_work\\agent-1\\170\\s\\
User Agent not found in file, need to replace with current
Previous user agent: D\:\\agent_work\\agent-2\\168\\s\\P
SED PROGRAM:
  s/'D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\P'/D:\agent_work\agent-1\170\s\/g
INPUT:   'myconfig.txt' line 1
PATTERN: #Tue Aug 01 14:16:13 AEST 2023
COMMAND: s/'D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\'/D:\agent_work\agent-1\170\s\/g
PATTERN: #Tue Aug 01 14:16:13 AEST 2023
END-OF-CYCLE:
INPUT:   'myconfig.txt' line 2
PATTERN: D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\PRIE\\\\Programs\\\\IEW340P3.NSP=ec656d00d2e5e12ae1eb3aa9771af464\\!\\:\\!null
COMMAND: s/'D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\'/D:\agent_work\agent-1\170\s\/g
PATTERN: D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\PRIE\\\\Programs\\\\IEW340P3.NSP=ec656d00d2e5e12ae1eb3aa9771af464\\!\\:\\!null
END-OF-CYCLE:
INPUT:   'myconfig.txt' line 3
PATTERN: D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\PRUT\\\\Maps\\\\UTRESM06.NSM=eb0e29846516c74be5763a8cd9ab22d8\\!\\:\\!null
COMMAND: s/'D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\'/D:\agent_work\agent-1\170\s\/g
PATTERN: D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\PRUT\\\\Maps\\\\UTRESM06.NSM=eb0e29846516c74be5763a8cd9ab22d8\\!\\:\\!null
END-OF-CYCLE:
INPUT:   'myconfig.txt' line 4
PATTERN: D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\PRMR\\\\Maps\\\\MRJ400M1.NSM=c4b10568d2dd5f88f255cf0192b0945d\\!\\:\\!null
COMMAND: s/'D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\'/D:\agent_work\agent-1\170\s\/g
PATTERN: D\\:\\\\agent_work\\\\agent-2\\\\168\\\\s\\\\PRMR\\\\Maps\\\\MRJ400M1.NSM=c4b10568d2dd5f88f255cf0192b0945d\\!\\:\\!null
END-OF-CYCLE:
```

**The full backslashes are not being used in the replacement string and it looks like sed is not matching the pattern for string replacement.**

Final result should be the file is replaced with the correct string including matching and retaining double backslashes using bash

Comment: [edit] your question to format your sample input/output/code as separate Code Blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The full backslashes are not being used in the replacement string and it looks like sed is not matching the pattern for string replacement.**

In particular:

> ```
>     sed -i --debug "s/'$replaceUser'/$userAgent/g" $file # <-- This is not working
> ```

I'm sure it isn't working.  At minimum, the single quotes in that command are inside double quotes, and therefore represent themselves.  Your file does not contain corresponding single-quote characters, so no lines will match that regex.  Additionally, the backslashes in the expansion of `userAgent` will not be understood literally by `sed`, so you would get an incorrect replacement. (Also, my `sed`, at least, does not understand `--debug`.)

---

The backslash is an escape character for `sed`.  To express a literal backslash, us a double backslash (`\\`).

The backslash is also an escape character for the shell, but that significance is suppressed by quoting with single quotes, which you appear to be using effectively for that purpose.

Your original code determines the old user agent from the file via a mix of a command substitution with `sed` and several `bash` parameter expansions, then tries to construct a `sed` expression to replace the old agent string with the new one.  But you are already using `sed`, and the user-agent identification is right in its wheelhouse, so why are you making it so complicated?

Possibly you have simplified a more complex real-world scenario, but with what you've actually presented, I would probably do something more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=myconfig.txt
userAgent='D\:\\agent_work\\agent-1\\170\\s\\'
echo "Current User agent: $userAgent"

if grep -q -F "$userAgent" "$file"; then
    echo "Found user agent, no need to replace"
else
    echo "User Agent not found in file, need to replace with current"
    sed -i -e '2,$s/^[^s]*s\\\\/'"${userAgent//\\/\\\\}/" "$file"
fi
```

In fact, I might even take out the user-agent test, and just do the substitution unconditionally:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=myconfig.txt
userAgent='D\:\\agent_work\\agent-1\\170\\s\\'

sed -i -e '2,$s/^[^s]*s\\\\/'"${userAgent//\\/\\\\}/" "$file"
```

That uses about the same approach as your original to select the currect user-agent string (everything from the beginning of a line to the first 's' followed by a double backslash, as opposed to everything up to the first 's' regardless of backslashes), and it substitutes the chosen user agent string for that on the second and all subsequent lines.

The main trick there is doubling the backslashes in the `sed` expression, both the literal part and the expansion of `$userAgent`.  The literal part is handled literally, and the `$userAgent` part with the pattern replacement feature of shell parameter expansion.  `${userAgent//\\/\\\\}` says the value of shell parameter `userAgent`, with all appearances of the pattern `\\` (which, being unquoted, represents a *single* backslash character) replaced by `\\\\` (which, being unquoted, represents *two* backslash characters).

Pay attention to the quoting details, too, however, as your original script is somewhat under-quoted.

---

If you need, for reasons not evident in the question, to stick closer to your original code, then you should be able to use the same kind of substitutions in the original code.  Maybe with something like this:

```
    sed -i --debug "s/${replaceUser//\\/\\\\}/${userAgent//\\/\\\\}/" "$file"
```

Comment: Great explanation,  thanks John will give it a try. This file has 17000 instances of user agent replacement,  cheers

Comment: I took your simple approach and just the the one liner replace - works a treat, those escape chars / double backslashes were a real problem. This ----> (sed -i -e '2,$s/^[^s]*s\\\\/'"${userAgent//\\/\\\\}/" "$file") Thank you!